# How to separate the data in the same "group by" in R?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, row, tidyr

I am trying to connect the link that mac address have passed which use the speed 4 km/hr to 100 km/hr.
I have the data frame of Link, Date, Mac address, Time, speed, Status. Status is the column that i check that "less than 4 km/hr but more than 100 km/hr" is True.
I would like to separate the trip of each mac address in a day. The trip will separate when False switch to True or True switch to False.

```
Link    Date      Mac address       Speed        Status
247-237 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 25.76649746  False
237-235 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 2.26099837   True
235-109 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 39.83606557  False
214-106 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 1.92997812   True
106-215 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 4.22249093   False
215-253 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 3.17867903   True
253-245 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 1.55383123   True
245-238 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 4.63823442   False
238-243 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 33.21573948  False
241-233 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 12.30440587  False
233-248 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 6.95569265   False
248-211 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 12.04411765  False
211-108 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 9.40500000   False
108-202 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 72.00000000  False
202-212 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 15.14371257  False
212-239 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 7.81390049   False
239-230 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 217.96363636 True
230-229 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 21.73090909  False
229-252 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 7.87826087   False
252-244 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 2.77302675   True
244-232 1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 0.21963016   True
```

I group the data by Date, Mac address and Status. Then i connect the link however, the link were connect consequently False/True all in the group by.

```
df <- df %>% arrange(Date,Mac address,Time) %>% group_by(Date,Mac address,Status) %>% summarise(Connect=paste(Link, collapse="_"))
```

Then, the result come like this.

```
Date      Mac address       Status Link
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 False  247-237_235-109_106-215_245-238_238-243_
                                   241-233_233-248_248-211_211-108_108-202_
                                   202-212_212-239_230-229_229-252
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 True   237-235_214-106_215-253_253-245_239-230_ 
                                   252-244_244-232
```

However, I expect the output of connected link in the sequence that False/True is switched.

```
Date      Mac address       Status Link
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 False 247-237
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 True  237-235
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 False 235-109
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 True  214-106
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 False 106-215
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 True  215-253_253-245
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 False 245-238_238-243_241-233_233-248_248-211_
                                  211-108_108-202_202-212_212-239
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 True  239-230
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 False 230-229_229-252
1/15/2018 00:00:00:00:00:00 True  252-244_244-232
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you expect the output you posted? What is the difference in Date, Mac address, and Status between 1st and 3rd row in expected output you provided?

Comment: It is my assumption to separate the trip of each mac address in a day. The trip will separate when False switch to True or True switch to False. True is the condition that the speed is less than 4 km/hr and more than 100 km/hr. So my expect output above is to have 10 trips of the mac address in a day. However, from the recent output, there are 2 trips which is not right as my assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a switch (I call it `Flag`) that changes when Status changes, which is what you're after.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
mutate(Flag = ifelse(Status == lag(Status), 0, 1),
    Flag = ifelse(is.na(Flag), 1, Flag),
    CumSum = cumsum(Flag)) %>%
group_by(Date, `Mac address`, Status, CumSum) %>%
summarize(Out = paste(Link, collapse = "_")) %>%
ungroup() %>%
arrange(CumSum)

df
```

EDIT: here is the output I get, which is identical to what you said you were expecting. Not sure what you mean in the comment about it still not

```
# output
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   Date    `Mac address`   Status CumSum Out                                   
<chr>   <chr>           <lgl>   <dbl> <chr>                                 
 1 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ FALSE       1 247-237                               
 2 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ TRUE        2 237-235                               
 3 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ FALSE       3 235-109                               
 4 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ TRUE        4 214-106                               
 5 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ FALSE       5 106-215                               
 6 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ TRUE        6 215-253_253-245                       
 7 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ FALSE       7 245-238_238-243_241-233_233-248_248-2~
 8 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ TRUE        8 239-230                               
 9 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ FALSE       9 230-229_229-252                       
10 1/15/2~ 00:00:00:00:00~ TRUE       10 252-244_244-232
```

Comment: Really thank you. However, the result come the same. They summarize all False and all True, not separate by each switching.

Comment: I added my output, which is identical to what you said you expected to get.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is my fault because I did with more data which has many days and many mac address at this moment. I add "group_by(Date, `Mac address`)" at the 2nd line in command, before mutation. Then the results come perfectly. Really thank you !!!

Comment: If my answer worked out - please consider accepting it (press the check mark on the left on the answer). And you're very welcome :-)